# StatefulPartitionedCall Tensorflow 2 layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I've trained the TF 2 OD API model, now I'm trying to run it through the OpenCV DNN module. I am running into a lot of problems, but most are related to the StatefulPartitionedCall layer. please explain to me:

1. what is this layer?
2. what is it for?
3. is it compulsory?
4. can i cut it out of the final model?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGSyH.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDB50.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs0HG.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.